# Create a set of N numbers with no common rational factor

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals

**Question:**

So I want to create a set of real numbers $\{a\}_{N} = \{a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{N}\}$ such that if there exists a common factor between all of the elements, it must be irrational.

In this way, the fraction $\frac{a_{i}}{a_{j}} \notin \mathbb{Q} \; \forall i \neq j \; \; (1 \leq i,j \leq N)$.

How can I create this set?

---

**Solution Attempt:**

We know that the square root of any prime number is irrational, therefore, just pick the set $\{a\}_{N}$ to be a set of square roots of distinct prime numbers.

What is tripping me up is that, the division of two irrational numbers can still be rational. An easy example is $\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2}{3} \in \mathbb{Q}$

---

**Disclaimer:**

I am not a number theorist, and have never taken a course on number theory, but I converted another problem I am working on to this problem. If I can solve this problem, I can solve the other problem, however, I don't know if this problem has a solution, and if it does, how to find it.

Comment: Speaking of "common factors" in this context is confusing, but the requirement that $i\neq j\implies \frac {a_i}{a_j}\notin \mathbb Q$ is clear.  Just take $a_i=e^i$.

Comment: @lulu That would do it. So generally, taking an irrational number to a power should do it too, right?

Comment: No, square root of 2 doesnt work, for instance.

Comment: No!  you need a transcendental number.  Won't work if you took $\sqrt 2$, say.

Comment: @Rhcpy99  exactly.

Comment: Note that your answer is also totally fine; you can show that if $p\neq q$ are both prime, then $\sqrt{p/q}$ is irrational by a small variant of the usual proof for $\sqrt{2}$: suppose $\sqrt{p/q}=m/n$; then $p/q=m^2/n^2$ or $qm^2=pn^2$. Now just count factors of $p$ on either side.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Excellent. This is what I was thinking, but couldn't put it down since I've never worked number theory problems. What do you mean count factors of p?

Comment: @lulu Alright, transcendental it is.

Comment: @TheDude Consider how many times $p$ divides either side.  Since it and $q$ are both prime, it can't divide $q$ at all; and since it's prime, it must divide $m^2$ an even number of times, so it divides the LHS an even number of times in total. Likewise, it must divide $n^2$ an even number of times, and of course it divides $p$ once, so this means that it divides the RHS an odd number of times in total. Therefore the two can't be equal.

Comment: (This is a slight variant of the usual argument by contradiction, which argues that since $p$ divides $pn^2$, it must divide $qm^2$, and thus $m^2$, and thus $m$; so $p^2$ divides $qm^2$, so it divides $pn^2$, so $p$ must divide $n^2$, and so $p$ divides $n$, contradicting an assumption that $m$ and $n$ have no common factor)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you, I really should open up a number theory book sometime!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha $ be any transcendental number (such as $e$ or $\pi$).  Then let $a_i=\alpha^i$.

To see that this works, suppose that $\frac {a_i}{a_j}\in \mathbb Q$ for some $i\neq j$.  Then we'd have $\alpha^i-c\times \alpha^j=0$ for $c\in \mathbb Q$ which would be a polynomial with rational coefficients satisfied by $\alpha$, contradicting transcendence.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-Take the primes $2,3,5,7,11,13,\cdots p_N$

You do have an example with the set
$$\{a\}_{N} = \{\sqrt2, \sqrt{2\cdot3},\sqrt{2\cdot3\cdot5}\cdots\sqrt{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots.p_N}\}$$

NOTE.-For all  non-zero real numbers $x,k$ you do have $x=kx_1$ for some real $x_1$. What is the "common factor" you want to say?

Comment: Hmmm! Interesting!

Comment: The problem is, dear friend, that you can always have a RATIONAL "common factor" for any set of real numbers (unless you want to dispense with the basic principle that "any quantity can be replaced by its equal").

Answer (score 1):

Well, your solution attempt also works. It's not that much different or more difficult to prove that $\frac{\sqrt{p}}{\sqrt{q}}$ is irrational for different primes $p,q$ than proving $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Your 'tripping me up' fear is not without reason, of course, but you circumvented it by chosing roots of primes, not just any number that isn't a square.

Comment: Combined with the comment above, this is a good answer.